# “LinearLayout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless” warning

Tags: java, android, warnings, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I need to use the layout_below property of a RelativeLayout and the weightSum property of the LinearLayout.

The code works perfectly but I get a disappointing warning.

I'm doing something wrong?

Tyvm!

Code attached:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/filtro"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:background="@color/grisOscuro"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_separator_filtro" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btFiltroCategoriasNoticias"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:background="@color/grisOscuro"
                android:text="@string/bt_noticias_categorias"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btBusqueda"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:background="@color/grisOscuro"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view. (But I can't use the layout_below property in the LinearLayout and neither the weightSum property in RelativeLayout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`layout_below` property doesn't have to belong to a `RelativeLayout`, you can modify your code and get rid of the `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/filtro"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="42dp"
android:background="@color/grisOscuro"
android:layout_below="@+id/header_separator_filtro" 
android:weightSum="1.0">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btFiltroCategoriasNoticias"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@color/grisOscuro"
            android:text="@string/bt_noticias_categorias"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btBusqueda"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:background="@color/grisOscuro"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ty! Solved... I really thought that I could not use the layout_below as property in LinearLayout

Comment: its the property of the child node, so, feel free to use with any type of child node.

Answer (score 2):

You always get this warning if a **Layout** have only childNode. In your case the `RelativeLayout` only contains a `LinearLayout`. In your example you could remove the `RelativeLayout` as it does not do anything.